# Android fill_parent issue

Tags: android

HI there. This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lv" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this the list view occupies full screen. What I want is list view to be full screen except button area without mentioning dp. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out some possibilities I found this to be helpful

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_above="@+id/bt"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks  all of you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

@mnish is quite right except that in Android 1.5 you have to declare ids before using them.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lv" />
```

You can use layout_above, layout_below, layout_toLeftOf, ...

Comment: Thats true. However, since i mentioned fill_parent as height, the button isn't visible.

Comment: Prevent this by putting android:layout_alignParentTop="true" on your listview

Answer (score 1):

I think a `LinearLayout` is more suited here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ListView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

(Yes, `wrap_content` is correct on `ListView`'s `layout_height`, the `layout_weight="1"` will ensure it expands as much as possible)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this:

write:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lv" />
```

before:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

like this:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lv" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

but I am not sure

Comment: You can't do that. You have to have declared the listview before you can reference it. Instead, set the button as alignparentbottom, and then set the listview above it