# How to show other views after list view height set to fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, include

To prevent multiple GetView calling I have set the height of ListView to fill_parent.

How to show other views than the ListView itself?

The following layout is inflated in a ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_viol_infraction"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/activity_prontuario_home" />
</LinearLayout>
```

where the included layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/prontuariohome_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3830622/1768336) won't work for view higher than a button

Comment: You cant do that if you use fill_parent for height.

Comment: How do you stop getview from getting called ? It will get called the number of times as the size of list items.

Comment: not clear what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for being not clear.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co) of the (probably) main thread asked here in Sof about the issue I was talking about.

After some tries I'm happy to give you the solution of my problem.

Giving another layout above the ListView lets the LV cuts the space not filled by the ListView itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_viol_infraction"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_prontuario_home" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you put wrap_content to ListView height instead of creating LL and assign its height as Wrap_content ?

Comment: Like said below, you need to set fill_parent, otherwise you will have the GetView method called more times than neede as explained here stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/1768336.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want to achieve, but if you NEED to have the height as `fill_parent` for some reason and can't be any other value, you can put the `ListView` with inside a `LinearLayout` with the `height="0dp"` and `weight="1"`. So would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_viol_infraction"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_prontuario_home" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Almost the solution I found!
Yes, of course you need to set fill_parent, otherwise you will have the GetView method called more times than neede as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/1768336.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in `ListView` tag

Comment: With this solution, GetView will be called more times than needed. Already tried.

Answer (score 0):

With android:layout_height="0dip" the view will take the rest of the free place

Comment: With this solution, GetView will be called more times than needed. Already tried.

Comment: it's no problem for getView to be called multiple times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157523/listview-getview-is-called-too-much-times

Answer (score 0):

You said this solution is wont work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_above="@+id/bt"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

just add it a `android:layout_above="@+id/bt"` to listview.

Comment: Yes because if you have a View with an high height, it will overlap the ListView. It's a workaround for small view only.
Already tried to add layout_above, same behaviour.

Comment: you can add 'android:minHeight="100dp"' too.

Comment: So bad solution, I would have a fixed height, and adding more items to the list view I will encounter graphic layout problem.

Comment: Then add 'android:maxHeight="100dp"' to view at below.

Comment: In my humble opinion you have to make layout as much generic as possible. Using min/maxHeight in this case, you lose this "generic rule"